# Solving differential eqution in a specific form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

for the following differential equation

$$\frac{dG}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\lambda G^{2}+\rho G-1$$

$\lambda$ and $\rho$ are constant, G is a function of t

This is then expressed in the form

$$\int_{0}^{G}\frac{1}{(G'-a)(G'+b)}dG'=\frac{1}{2}\lambda\int_{T}^{t}dt$$

where

$$b,a=\frac{\pm \rho +\sqrt{\rho ^ 2 + 2\lambda}}{\lambda}$$

I need to show that

$$G(t;T) = \frac{2(e^{\psi (T-t)}-1)}{(\rho+\psi)(e^{\psi(T-t)}-1)+2\psi}$$

where

$$\psi = \sqrt{\rho^2+2\lambda}$$

many thanks!

Comment: Just integrate using partial fractions. Here you'll find similar problems: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+solve+logistic+equation

Comment: thanks for hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your initial condition is $G(T)=0$. This restricts the domain of integration to $G \in (-b,a)$

Using partial fractions

$$ \frac{1}{(a-G')(b+G')} = \frac{1}{a+b}\left(\frac{1}{a-G'}+\frac{1}{b+G'}\right) $$

where $a+b= \frac{2\psi}{\lambda}$. Integrating the above gives

$$ \frac{\lambda}{2\psi}\big[\ln(b+G)-\ln(a-G) - \ln b + \ln a\big] = \frac{\lambda}{2}(T-t) $$

or

$$ \frac{a(b+G)}{b(a-G)} = e^{\psi(T-t)} $$

Do some algebra to get

$$ G = \frac{ab\big(e^{\psi(T-t)}-1\big)}{be^{\psi(T-t)}+a} $$

You have $ab = \frac{2}{\lambda}$ so this simplifies to

$$ G = \frac{2\big(e^{\psi(T-t)}-1\big)}{(\psi+\rho)e^{\psi(T-t)}+(\psi-\rho)} = \frac{2\big(e^{\psi(T-t)}-1\big)}{(\psi+\rho)\big(e^{\psi(T-t)}-1\big)+2\psi} $$